# Unexpected error using Node.js's Express with vhosts

Tags: node.js, express, vhosts

Here's the error:

[image]

Here's the code:

`runapps.js:`

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var first  = require('./apps/ghost_gforce/index.js').app;
var second = require('./apps/ghost_blog2/index.js').app;

app
.use(express.vhost('gforce/main', first))
.use(express.vhost('gforce/blog2', second))
.listen(80);
```

running this straight from node like below works perfectly:

```
node apps\ghost_gforce\index.js
```

UPDATE:: ran:

```
npm install
```

within the node app directory, so nothing should be missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since it seems you've updated Express to 4.x, [`vhost` will no longer be bundled](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware). It's now [its own package](http://npmjs.org/package/vhost) that you'll need to install and `require()` separately. See the [migration guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In your test you are calling a relative path:

```
apps\ghost_gforce\index.js
```

But in your code you are using a path based on the root of your filesystem:

```
/apps/ghost_blog2/index.js
```

Try this:

```
var first  = require('./apps/ghost_gforce/index.js').app;
var second = require('./apps/ghost_blog2/index.js').app;
```

Comment: Ah! You beat me to updating my question. I did try that but now I'm getting the error: "Error: Most muddleware (like vhost} is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately." Which is weird, because I ran the `npm install` command to install all required modules.